# crear área circular a partir de coordenadas javascript

Tags: javascript, geolocalización

Buen dia a todos, tengo este array de objetos:

```
let coords = {
  "userCoords": [4.8005119999999994,-75.69080319999999],
  "coordOne": [4.3005119999999994,-75.69080319999999],
  "coordTwo": [7.8005119999999994,-5.69080319999999],
  "coordThree": [4.8005119999999994,-75.66080319999999],
  "area": 2
}
```

y necesito crear un filtro de coordenadas por área circular del userCoords por kilómetros teniendo en cuenta el valor del área y ver si el resto de coordenadas están dentro de esa área y que me devuelva los objetos que si están dentro de esa área.
tengo esto hecho pero no se si este correcto para lo que quiero lograr:

```
//radio circular de coordenadas
let radioCirculo = Math.min(coords.userCoords[0], coords.userCoords[1]) / 2;
console.log(radioCirculo)

//centro del circulo
let x = coords.userCoords[0] / 2;
let y = coords.userCoords[1] / 2;

console.log(x,y)
```

alguna idea de cómo lograrlo? cualquier ayuda me serviria mucho.
gracias.

Comment: Entiendo que las coordenadas del usuario (`userCoords`) representa el centro de la circunferencia. El radio de la misma estaría dado en *km*, por el valor de `area`. Y lo que necesitas determinar es si los puntos representados por las coordenadas en `coordOne`, `coordTwo` y `coordThree` se encuentran dentro o fuera de la circunferencia definida anteriormente. ¿Es esto correcto?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No entendí muy bien tu código, pero creo haber entendido la pregunta.

A veces puede parecer "complicado" trabajar con coordenadas, pues la tierra no es plana, por lo que no se debe aplicar geometría euclideana, sino la geometría esférica.

### Análisis matemático del problema

Por definición, para saber si un punto se encuentra dentro del área circular, basta con saber si la distancia del punto al centro del círculo es menor o igual al radio.

Ahora, el problema es entonces saber cuál es la distancia del punto al centro del círculo.

Aplicar la fórmula de distancia entre puntos que siempre hemos conocido no sirve, pues es sólo aplicable para un espacio euclideano, y evidentemente no estamos trabajando en un espacio euclideano.

Y de hecho, la ruta más corta para llegar a un determinado punto, no es una recta como sucede en el espacio euclideano.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la Figura [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X35oS.png) se puede observar eso.

Ahora entonces, supongamos que de la Figura [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X35oS.png) queremos calcular la distancia **c** entre los puntos **w** y **v**, para ello utilizaremos la [fórmula de Haversine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) que nos permite calcular el ángulo central entre dos puntos.

¿Pero para qué queremos el ángulo, si buscamos la distancia? Porque si recordamos un poco, la longitud de arco (lo que estamos buscando) divido entre el radio del círculo (en este caso esfera, pero lo reducimos a dos dimensiones en donde se encuentran **v**, **w** y el centro de la esfera pues no necesitamos nada más) es igual al ángulo central.

[image: arc length]

Donde **big-theta** es el ángulo central, **S** es la longitud de arco y **r** es el radio

Entonces por lo tanto, conociendo el radio y el ángulo podemos sacar la distancia entre los puntos.

El radio es el radio de la tierra porque pues, estamos trabajando con coordenadas GPS.

Entonces, en conclusión debemos hacer los siguientes sencillos pasos para calcular la distancia esférica entre dos puntos en una esfera:

1. Obtener la función haversine del ángulo central entre los dos puntos con la fórmula de haversine. Revisa el [link de Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) para saber los detalles de la fórmula.

[image: haverside]

[image: haverside 2]

2. Aplicar la función inversa a lo obtenido en el paso anterior para obtener el ángulo central entre los dos puntos.
3. Calcular la distancia entre los puntos con la fórmula de [longitud de arco](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZCkU.png), pues ya conocemos el ángulo central y el radio.

### Implementación en JS

Conociendo lo anterior es sencillo programarlo, sin embargo debemos de tomar en cuenta que las coordenadas que proporcionaste son coordenadas **decimales** y se requieren coordenadas en **radianes**, entonces basta simplemente con convertir de grados decimales a radianes. Para ello está la siguiente función

```javascript
const deg2Rad = degrees => degrees * Math.PI / 180;
```

Luego la fórmula [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXyfU.png) de haversine queda así

```javascript
const hav = theta => (1 - Math.cos(theta)) / 2;
```

Y con esas dos funciones ya podemos programar otra función que realice el paso 1. Dicha función es la siguiente.

```javascript
const havPoints = (point1, point2) => {
    // latitudes in radians
    const lat1 = deg2Rad(point1.latitude);
    const lat2 = deg2Rad(point2.latitude);

    // longitudes in radians
    const long1 = deg2Rad(point1.longitude);
    const long2 = deg2Rad(point2.longitude);

    // haversine formula
    return hav(lat2 - lat1) + Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2) * hav(long2 - long1);
};
```

Por último, para hacer el paso 2 y 3, utilizamos la siguiente función

```javascript
const calculateDistance = (point1, point2, radius=6_371) => {
    // hav(central angle)
    const hav_central_angle = havPoints(point1, point2);

    // now that we have the haversine of the central angle its time to get the central angle by applying the inverse
    // central angle = archav(hav(central angle)) = 2arcsin(hav(central angle))
    const central_angle = 2 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(hav_central_angle));

    // now just apply the well known formula d = r * theta
    return radius * central_angle;
};
```

Espero que eso te haya servido de ayuda, disculpa los comentarios en inglés en el código, usualmente siempre programo en inglés, pero a final de cuentas creo que el cómo sacar la distancia entre dos puntos quedó claro.

Teniendo estas funciones, es fácil programar la función que filtré las coordenadas que están dentro del círculo, simplemente hay que revisar si la distancia del centro del círculo al punto es menor o igual que el radio del círculo, si es así, entonces, obviamente está dentro.

### Snippet completo

Te dejo un snippet para que lo veas en acción

```js
/**
 * Converts the given degrees to radians
 * @param degrees degrees :)
 * @return the equivalent in radians
 */
const deg2Rad = degrees => degrees * Math.PI / 180;

/**
 * Calculates de haversine of the central angle between two points
 * @param point1 an object with properties latitude and longitude in DEGREES
 * @param point2 an object with properties latitude and longitude in DEGREES
 * @return the middle angle (in radians) between the two points
 */
const havPoints = (point1, point2) => {
    // latitudes in radians
    const lat1 = deg2Rad(point1.latitude);
    const lat2 = deg2Rad(point2.latitude);

    // longitudes in radians
    const long1 = deg2Rad(point1.longitude);
    const long2 = deg2Rad(point2.longitude);

    // haversine formula
    return hav(lat2 - lat1) + Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2) * hav(long2 - long1);
};

/**
 * Calculates the haversine of the given angle
 * @param theta the ange in RADIANS
 * @return the haversine in radians
 */
const hav = theta => (1 - Math.cos(theta)) / 2;

/**
 * Uses the haversine function to calculate the SPHERICAL distance between two points
 * @param point1 an object with properties latitude and longitude in DEGREES
 * @param point2 an object with properties latitude and longitude in DEGREES
 * @param radius the radius of the sphere in km. Default is the radius of the earth -> 6,371km
 * @return the distance in km between the two points
 */
const calculateDistance = (point1, point2, radius=6_371) => {
    // hav(central angle)
    const hav_central_angle = havPoints(point1, point2);

    // now that we have the haversine of the central angle its time to get the central angle by applying the inverse
    // central angle = archav(hav(central angle)) = 2arcsin(hav(central angle))
    const central_angle = 2 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(hav_central_angle));

    // now just apply the well known formula d = r * theta
    return radius * central_angle;
};

const filterCoordsByDistance = (center, points, minAcceptableDistance) => points.filter(
    point => calculateDistance(center, point) <= minAcceptableDistance
);

const transformData = () => {
    let coords = {
        "coordOne": [4.3005119999999994, -75.69080319999999],
        "coordTwo": [7.8005119999999994,-5.69080319999999],
        "coordThree": [4.8005119999999994,-75.66080319999999],
    }
    return Object.values(coords).map(coords => {
        return {
            latitude: coords[0],
            longitude: coords[1]
        }
    });
}

const center = {
    latitude: 4.8005119999999994,
    longitude: -75.69080319999999
};

const data = transformData();

console.log(`Distancias de los puntos al centro, en orden: ${data.map(point => calculateDistance(center, point)).sort()}`);

const circleRadius = 100;
const pointsInRange = filterCoordsByDistance(center, transformData(), circleRadius);

console.log(`Puntos que están en un radio de ${circleRadius}km del centro: ${JSON.stringify(pointsInRange)}`);
```

Si lo ejecutaste, habrás visto que sólo un punto no está dentro del círculo con radio de 100km, si quieres comprobarlo ve a Google Maps o a alguno otro similar y calcula la distancia entre los tres puntos con el centro del círculo y verás que en efecto, las distancias son correctas y sólo deben existir dos puntos en el círculo de radio 100km.

**Últimas notas**

- Nuevamente perdón por el código en inglés, espero la explicación que fue dada sea suficiente.
- El código no está 100% testeado y listo para producción obviamente.
- Mencionas que se debe filtrar de acuerdo al área circular, supongo que te refieres al radio, en cualquier caso puedes obtener el radio fácilmente.

Answer (score 1):

la respuesta mas simple y probablemente la que buscas, es la función haversine, que dadas dos coordenadas retorna la distancia en kilometros entre ambos puntos. Luego simplemente comparas la distancia con el radio del circulo y si es menor o igual asumimos que esta dentro, te dejo el código que yo uso en python adaptado a javascript.

```
const get_distance_in_km = ([lat1, lon1], [lat2, lon2]) => {
  //   Se asume que los dos parametros son listas en formato [latitud, longitud]
  const toRadians = (n) => n * (Math.PI / 180);
  const distance = (a, b) => (Math.PI / 180) * (a - b);

  const EARTH_RADIUS_IN_KM = 6371;

  const dLat = distance(lat2, lat1);
  const dLon = distance(lon2, lon1);

  lat1 = toRadians(lat1);
  lat2 = toRadians(lat2);

  const a =
    Math.pow(Math.sin(dLat / 2), 2) +
    Math.pow(Math.sin(dLon / 2), 2) * Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2);

  const c = 2 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a));

  var finalDistance = EARTH_RADIUS_IN_KM * c;
  return finalDistance;
};

console.log(
  get_distance_in_km(
    [4.8005119999999994, -75.69080319999999],
    [4.3005119999999994, -75.69080319999999]
  )
);
```

Asumiendo que tienes un punto central y una lista de coordenadas para verificar si están dentro de un radio, usaría un código como este:

```
const filter_coords_by_distance=(center, coords, distance)=>{
    return coords.filter(coord => get_distance_in_km(center, coord) <= distance)
}
```